# How to show an error message when form validation fails if form added to page with formBuilder->getForm()

Tags: forms

I have a number of pages in my Drupal 8 application where a template is returned from a controller method, and that template has a number of forms on it.  I build the form in the controller method using formBuilder->getForm(), and then I set that output to a theme variable which the template renders.  So something like this:

**Render Form**

```
$addDocumentForm = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\candidate_portal_candidate\Form\AddDocumentForm');
```

**Add to theme variable**

```
return array(
  array(
    '#theme' => 'candidate_dashboard',
    '#add_document_form' => $addDocumentForm,
    )
)
```

**Render Form in Twig Template**

```
<div id="addDocForm" class="modal1" style="display:none"><div class="modal-content left"><span onclick='closeModal("addDocForm")' class="closeModal">&times;</span><br/>{{add_document_form}}</div></div>
```

This works fine, and seemed like an OK way to put multiple forms on one page.  However, the problem is when there is an error in validateForm() when I submit one of the forms.  Instead of returning to the current page with an error on the page, drupal redirects to a page with **only** the invalid form on it.

How can I get Drupal to show an error message on the actual page the form is rendered on?